# Execute string method on integer column in Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have custom method for Linq Expression which I call as

```
query = query.Where(FilterLinqHelper.ContainsPredicate<T>(columnName, searchValue));
```

the method is working for string column, but for integer it throw error that integer cannot execute `.Contains()` method. 
The if statement `if (member.Type == typeof(int))` was added later.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsPredicate<T>(string columnName, object searchValue)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var x = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    var member = Expression.Property(x, columnName);
    Expression expression;
    ConstantExpression constant;

    // Contains
    if (member.Type == typeof(int))
    {
         // ?
    }
    else
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(string));
        var call = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, x);
    }
}
```

How can i execute `ToString()` method on integer column and after that execute `.Contains()` method?

Comment: What do you expect this method to return? an `int` value might  have different meanings of "contains" - "equal to" being the most obvious but one might think of the number 15 as containing 3 and 5 as it's a multiple of both these numbers, or of the number 123 as containing 3, 20 and 100. You first need to decide what "contains" means.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the contains mean the same as contains of string in this case, so for example integer 123465 contains value 123 and should return true.

Comment: @HimBromBeere exactly and my question is how in this case

Comment: But the problem is, that i already have one Expression.Call which is entry into Expression.Lambda, I also tried .ToString() directly on searchValue but it does not change the type of the constant. Maybe the Expression Calls may be chained somehow. I will try `Expression.Convert` now instead.

Comment: Why not `var call = Expression.Call(member.ToString(), method, constant);`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled `member` is an `Expression`, not the actual `int`.`ToString`-ing it will result in soemthing like `System.Linq.Exression.PropertyExpression`.

Comment: I've suspected it wouldn't be this easy... No real experience with expressions so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `ToString()` on your member, and pass result to call of `Contains` method.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsPredicate<T>(string columnName, object searchValue)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var x = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    var member = Expression.Property(x, columnName);
    ConstantExpression constant;

    // Contains
    if (member.Type == typeof(int))
    {
        MethodInfo toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");

        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue.ToString());
        var memberToStringCall = Expression.Call(member, toStringMethod);
        var call = Expression.Call(memberToStringCall, method, constant);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, x);
    }
    else
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(string));
        var call = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to add: be careful with ToString() and Contains() when working with integers. If that column has an index (no matter if clustered or not), the SQL will convert the data to varchar and then apply LIKE '%VALUE%', which means a full table scan (hogging the CPU and memory if working with 100Ks+ of rows). The only solution is to implement the "like" via numeric comparison (getting LEN(rows count) and then concatenate several numeric queries